# File Upload support of Jmter HTTP2 sampler

Tags: jmeter, http2

I would like to use the "File Upload" option in the HTTP2 sampler to load test a server that supports HTTP2 with different message sizes.

I have tried out the "File Upload" option in the HTTP2 sampler for this and observed that the path provided for the "file path" getting removed when we move across the other samplers, therefore it's not possible to use the file upload option in the HTTP2 sampler.[image]

After moving to another sampler, "file path" got removed.[image]

May I know how can send different files as payload of the POST request when using HTTP2 sampler?

I'm using Apache Jmeter 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on second screenshot you are on different tab: first screen is on File Upload tab, while second is on Parameters tab

Comment: it redirects to the parameters tab, and the defined file path is missing in file upload tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround for this issue we can use "**__FileToString**" function in Jmeter.

For example : *${__FileToString(${__P(payload)},,)}*